# using CTE (common table expressions) in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
with cte as
(
select rowid from batchinfo where datapath like '%thc%'
)

select * from qvalues where rowid in cte
```

i am getting this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near 'cte'.

does anyone know what am doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you are treating a CTE as a subquery, where instead it should be used more like a table.

try this

```
;with cte as
(
select rowid from batchinfo where datapath like '%thc%'
)
select * from qvalues 
INNER JOIN cte on cte.rowid=qvalues.rowid
```

Comment: I don't think you need the words "more like" in "..used more like a table" as they can only be used as tables :) +1 for putting the semicolon at the start of the statement to avoid errors when CTE are used in larger statements.

Answer (score 1):

As casually alluded to in Al W's answer (and Tony's comment). The fact that the error is being described as occurring on line 6 means that it's not the first statement in the batch. Which means that you need to have a semicolon before the [WITH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) keyword:

> When a CTE is used in a statement that is part of a batch, the statement before it must be followed by a semicolon.

Also, from [Transact-SQL Syntax conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx):

> Although the semicolon is not required for most statements in this version of SQL Server, it will be required in a future version.

So it's worth getting in the habit of putting the semicolons in.